# Queries on multiple fields, each with a custom method, with django-filter

Tags: django, django-filter

I have this filter:

```
class MsTuneFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

def all_titles(self, queryset, name, value):
    return MsTune.objects.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=value) | Q(title__icontains=value) | Q(alt_title__icontains=value)
    )

def ind_1(self, queryset, name, value):
    return MsTune.objects.filter(
        Q(index_standard_1__startswith=value) | Q(index_gore_1__startswith=value) | Q(alt_index_gore_1__startswith=value) | Q(alt_index_standard_1__startswith=value)
    )

title = django_filters.CharFilter(method='all_titles', label="All title fields")
index_standard_1 = django_filters.CharFilter(method='ind_1', label="Index 1")

class Meta:
    model = MsTune
    fields = ['index_standard_1', 'title', ....]
```

It all works well when I'm making queries which do not involve both 'title' and 'index_standard_1'. Nevertheless, if I'm searching for something with a specific title AND with a specific index, either the index search or the title is ignored, i.e. the query returns all the indexes or all the titles, ignoring a parameter of my search. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to filter the `queryset`, not make two querysets from the model, so:

```
def all_titles(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(
        Q(name__icontains=value) | Q(title__icontains=value) | Q(alt_title__icontains=value)
    )

def ind_1(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(
        Q(index_standard_1__startswith=value) | Q(index_gore_1__startswith=value) | Q(alt_index_gore_1__startswith=value) | Q(alt_index_standard_1__startswith=value)
    )
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much, it now works like a charm. I need to wait 6 hours for accepting your answer.